# Print PDF with text layer through virtual XPS printer

Tags: pdf, openxml, ghostscript, xps

If I use "MS XPS Document Writer" printer and print Word document from Word application I get XPS document with text layer.

But if I use same print driver from Adobe Reader or SumatraPDF application to print PDF document (which has text layer) I get XPS without text layer.

Decompressing Adobe Reader produced XPS file and looking at XML files that represents the document contents, I see that for example `.\Documents\1\Pages\1.fpage` contains vector data in XML format, but unlike Word print there is no `.\Documents\1\Resources\Fonts\` folder in XPS structure and consequently no reference to fonts from `.\Documents\1\Resources\Fonts\` in `.\Documents\1\Pages\1.fpage` like it is with Word virtual print.

Does anyone know how to print PDF file to XPS (so w/o using third party software for conversion) and get XPS with text layer?

Comment: *PDF document (which has text layer)* - what do you mean by this? PDF does not have a concept of dedicated *text layers*.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Let me clarify: So I'm talking about regular PDF with text, not about scanned image converted to PDF or PDF processed with OCR. For example take this file as sample: [sample.pdf](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf). Thanks for your input

Comment: If you don't want to use third-party software, why have you tagged this with Ghostscript ?

Comment: @KenS: thanks for your interest! Bounty contains description why I tagged this question with GhostScript, but perhaps it doesn't appear as obvious so I'll just copy/paste bounty description located just below: `With this bounty, I'll also reward an answer that may include 3rd party software like XPS version of GhostScript`

Comment: Ah OK I missed that, I was reading the original question. I'm afraid I don't know any way to do this, and indeed its somewhat problematic in the general case. PDF can have fonts of multiple different types which are not available in XPS and not readily converted into TrueType. In addition text can be used in PDF in ways which are also not available in XPS and it wouldn't be possible to create the correct visual representation while still maintaining the text as text. There is an xpswrite device in Ghostscript but at present it doesn't attempt this feat.